# oracle apex interactive report template

Tags: oracle-apex

I have several similar interactive reports. I want to have some kind of a template to which all reports will adhere. For example each report need to have a button and it's tedious to add button to each new report. If I want to change something in common part of all reports, I will need to go through all reports and apply changes that is difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an ideal solution for you, but here are some things you can do to make creating new reports easier:

1. When creating a new Interactive Report (IR) region in an application, you could start by copying an existing IR in the same application.  This gives you the option to copy any associated items and buttons at the same time.
2. You can create a "template" page (I normally call it a "skeleton" page to avoid confusion with the concept of Apex templates) with a typical set of components: IR region, standard buttons, items, processes.  To create a new report, create a new page as a copy of the skeleton page and then modify it as required.

Neither of these deal with your second problem: if at a later date you decide that all IR regions should have a new "Foo" button, you are going to have to change each one individually.  You could consider an approach using the Apex Builder APIs to generate such buttons, but if you did that (I have in the past) you wouldn't be supported by Oracle!